# Cannot find the correct query

Tags: sql

Sorry for my bad English.
I have to retrieve all the records who have the value evalWaarde 3 and at the same time they must belong at the same time to agLkrid 1, 2935 and 2932.
I know that agLkrid in (1,2932,2935)is not a good solution but I don’t find another.
So actually there is just one record : WJLUITV015
Any help??

SELECT  agClid, aglkrid, evalWaarde  FROM agenda2 as a JOIN evaluaties2 as e ON a.agclid = e.evalclid and agLkrid = evallkrid 
WHERE (agSchoolid='18' and agclid like 'WJLUI%' and agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) 
and agDatum >=   '2013/01/01' and agDatum <=   '2013/02/12' AND (evalWaarde  = 3))
group by agclid, aglkrid, evalWaarde

agClid          agLkrid  evalWaarde
WJLUIAT005  1   3
WJLUIBV005  1   3
WJLUIDV010  1   3
WJLUIDV030  1   3
WJLUITV015  1   3
WJLUIBV005  2932    3
WJLUITV015  2932    3
WJLUITV015  2935    3
WJLUITV020  2935    3

Comment: What makes you say that "agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) is not a good solution"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT agClid, evalWaarde 
FROM agenda2 as a 
    JOIN evaluaties2 as e 
        ON a.agclid = e.evalclid and agLkrid = evallkrid 
WHERE agSchoolid='18' 
    and agclid like 'WJLUI%' 
    and agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) 
    and agDatum >= '2013/01/01' 
    and agDatum <= '2013/02/12' 
    AND evalWaarde = 3
GROUP BY agclid, evalWaarde
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT agLkrid) = 3
```

You don't need the `DISTINCT` in your `COUNT` if there is a unique constraint on those fields in that table.

And I'm not sure about the `JOIN` and other `WHERE` criteria -- I'm assuming that was working correctly for you and your question was around agLkrid.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/171d9/1) with just the one table returning the single result.  And that query as well:

```
SELECT agClid, evalWaarde 
FROM agenda2 
WHERE agclid like 'WJLUI%' 
    and agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) 
    AND evalWaarde = 3
GROUP BY agclid, evalWaarde
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT agLkrid) = 3
```

This returns WJLUITV015.

Comment: Thxs, this result is just a piece off the whole query ... i continue with that result and see if all the query will work ...

Comment: @user2065400 -- huh?  Forget the link?

Comment: SELECT clid, cldoel, clanker, clprefix, clleerlijn, f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM Clusters  
WHERE clleerlijn like 'WJNLLUI%'   AND (f3 IS NOT NULL  OR f4 IS NOT NULL )
AND clid IN 
(Select agClid FROM agenda2 as a JOIN evaluaties2 as e ON a.agclid = e.evalclid
WHERE (agSchoolid='18' and agDatum >=   '2013/01/01' and agDatum <=   '2013/02/12'))
and clid not in .... and there i want to put the new query ... but i always get 'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @user2065400 -- that means you can't have multiple fields in your select list when using IN -- remove evalWaarde from your select list since you really only want agClid.  You can also remove it from your GROUP BY -- but that won't matter since it's in your WHERE as well. See if that works...

Comment: I found a way, but the query is long, can I show it to you so that you can add a comment ??? But the query is too long I cannot put him in this box is tere another way ???

Comment: @user2065400 -- please consider marking this answer as accepted then posting a new question so I can review the longer query.  Best regards.